# Visual Studio: Collecting the members of an interface in the same region

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, interface

I find it useful to right-click on an interface, and click "Implement Interface." This will create any missing interface members in a new region. However, if your interface has recently changed (ie some of the members already exist, some do not) the members will not be placed together in the same region.

**Is there an easy way to collect all the members of a given interface in the same #region?**

For bonus points, is it possible to have the members moved so they appear in the same order as in the interface declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio of any edition; I don't think it's possible.

With the third party plugin ReSharper I think so (reformat the code after the interface implementation).

Comment: I have found it in the options: ReSharper | Options | Languages | C# | Type Members Layout. Thanks